# Is it an unsafe practice to symlink /etc conf files?

Tags: configuration, git, configuration-management, symbolic-link, symlink

To manage the configuration of a server, I keep some configuration flies (located in /etc) under version control (in the home folder) and then symlink to them from their /etc locations:

```
/etc/someprog/c.conf -> /home/ubuntu/etc-config/someprog/c.conf
```

Is this a reasonable approach? Any potential downsides?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I noticed you add `git` as a tag--it sounds like `/home/ubuntu/etc-config` is a git repository with all your configs in it.  In which case, it sounds like you're trying to manage configuration files from a central location.  If that's the case, I highly recommend looking for a real solution.

Take a look at something like puppet, chef, cfengine, or any of the major configuration manage engines out there.  Many of them are free and open source, widely used, and are typically *very* easy to setup and manage.  If you're trying to use a "lightweight" method instead, you'll likely come to regret it later.

Comment: +1 for "use a real configuration engine"

Comment: fair point :)   I had a feeling that might be the answer to this question.

what's your config engine of choice?

Comment: I'm partial to puppet, but there as many opinions as there are configuration management systems. :)  Since a lot of them have different strengths and weaknesses, definitely try a few of them out.  Most packages manages (i.e., apt) have them--so give them a whirl!  Nothing will tell you if it fits like trying it on.

Answer (score 3):

If these are on different filesystems, then this is a very bad idea.  If the other filesystem does not mount then you will have problems.

Comment: Fair point. In this case it's the same filesystem

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use symlinks like this. If you break the link (for any number of reasons) you'll break the config. It's more appropriate to point the server/daemon/app to the actual location of the config file in the init script.

If you *just* want version control, look at RCS. I've actually found git to be a poor stand-alone server config solution (no locking, no permissions management, the whole directory becomes the repo). If you need something more robust for configuration management, then I'd strongly suggest taking a look at Puppet, Chef, or (gasp) CFEngine.